# Python subprocess call powershell does not return in pycharm IDE

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess, pydev, pycharm

I am using pycharm IDE for my development. When using pycharm IDE to debug the following simple python program that calls a powershell script, it seems that it does not return and it got stuck inside the powershell. However, if just run it on commnad line (python callps.py), it runs and returns. I saw that someone reported an issue on: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-12088 but it has not been resolved and there is no update on this. Anyone has a tip to resolve this, Thanks.
Cloud Guy.

Powershell script: samplePowerShell.ps1:

```
$x = 1
$y = 2
return $x, $y
```

python script: callps.py:

```
import subprocess
cmd = ['powershell', '-ExecutionPolicy', 'RemoteSigned', '-File', 'samplePowerShell.ps1']
returncode = subprocess.call(cmd)
print "Done"
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, however, I still see the same behavior.

Comment: Sorry that I was not clear. Your 2nd suggestion, which specifies the PIPE, works.

Answer (score 2):

A Windows process has three standard handles named `StandardInput`, `StandardOutput`, and `StandardError`. They're typically handles for console I/O, pipes, or disk files. Usually they're inherited from the parent process, either implicitly or by explicitly setting them in the [`STARTUPINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that the parent passes to [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

PyCharm probably executes the interpreter using piped standard I/O. If that's the case, then PowerShell inherits these handles and probably does a blocking read of the input pipe.

To get around this you can supply your own pipes to PowerShell and then [`communicate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate).

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['powershell.exe',
       '-ExecutionPolicy', 'RemoteSigned',
       '-File', 'samplePowerShell.ps1']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, 
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
returncode = p.wait()
print returncode
```